# Understanding curl POST request command that contains multiple Content-Type headers

Tags: json, post, curl, http-headers

The following curl command:

```
curl -v -F 'json={"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"582984001","itemState":"INACTIVE"},"token":"jCoXH5OAMYQtXm1sg62KAF3ysG90YLagEECDAdlhg.."}}' https://api.somewebservice.com/services/post
```

Produces this output:

```
{"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"55269001","itemState":"INACTIVE"},"token":"jCoXH1sg62KAF3ysG90YLagEECTP16uOUSg_fDAdlhg.."}}' https://api.somewebservice.com/services/post
*   Trying 64.74.101.65...
* Connected to api.somewebservice.com (64.74.101.65) port 443 (#0)
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.0, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.0, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=Issued through Somewebservice Inc. E-PKI Manager; OU=COMODO SSL; CN=api.brightcove.com
*    start date: 2015-09-02 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-10-09 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.somewebservice.com matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /services/post HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: api.somewebservice.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 294
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5106835c8f9f70f9
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 943
< Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 22:29:23 GMT
< Server: somewebservice
<
* Connection #0 to host api.somewebservice.com left intact
{"result": {"id":55225001,"name":"Taxpayers pay to cover tattoos","adKeys":null,"shortDescription":"Opening statements are set to begin in the trial.","longDescription":null,"creationDate":"1260220396","publishedDate":"12603101609","lastModifiedDate":"1460352526","linkURL":null,"linkText":null,"tags":["Crime","national","wtsp","neo-nazi","court","taxpayers","News","David","john"],"videoStillURL":"http:\/\/bcdownload.net\/wtsp\/35134001\/3508134001_55110080001_59001.jpg?pubId=35134001","thumbnailURL":"http:\/\/bcdownload.edgesuite.net\/wtsp\/87134001\/350134001_55110081001_th-55100159001.jpg?pubId=35084001","referenceId":"7cf007503e2ee37a","length":112106,"economics":"AD_SUPPORTED","playsTotal":248,"playsTrailingWeek":0}, "error": null, "id": null}
```

There are two 'Content-Type' objects in the above output:

```
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
```

and

```
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

According to the [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), using `-F` allows curl to send data as a multi-part form, but then the `json=` is something I can't find in the docs. I'm assuming it's converting the dictionary/string:

```
{"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"582984001","itemState":"INACTIVE"},"token":"jCoXH5OAMYQtXm1sg62KAF3ysG90YLagEECDAdlhg.."}}
```

to JSON? Or more precisely, it's adding the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header to the POST request? So is this essentially a POST request with two distinct headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `Content-Type` header is part of the client's *request* header and the second one is part of the server's *response* header. The request and the response are separated by 2 CRLFs. Request and response each have their own Content-Types.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. So the actual POST request that's executed with this curl command has as its header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` ?

Comment: Is the `json=` in the command converting that dictionary/string into a json format or something? I can't seem to find an example in the curl docs of `json=` although I could have missed it.

Comment: `json=` actually looks like the key= portion of a key/value pair, the same as what you are probably used to seeing in query strings in HTTP `GET` requests. Really, the value portion (i.e. the actual json data) should be url encoded if you're submitting it this way because if the json happens to contain an ampersand, your json would be truncated.

Comment: Designing a REST API this way seems a little goofy to me but if the server is giving you a `200 OK` response, then I guess you've got the request correct. A more sane REST API design would have you post just the json data (without the `json=` in front) and with `Content-Type: application/json` in the request header.

Comment: I agree, I've tried using Python-Request library for this, which usually works pretty seamlessly, but I cannot get that json data to POST successfully. I just stumbled upon this curl command, and it works flawlessly, but I've yet to recreate it in Python.

Comment: Try your curl command from the question without the `-F`. I suspect it might still work.

Comment: Tried that and the server came back with `{"error": {"name":"PostRequiredError","message":"methods that change data must be called using POST requests","code":202}, "result": null, "id": null}`

Comment: Oh, you still need to do an HTTP `POST` instead of a `GET`, you just don't need it to be multipart. Change `-F` to `--data`.

Comment: Wow, this was totally weird, but I finally just go my Python script to do the same thing as this curl command, except that in my Python script the header was set to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead of `'multipart/form'` like with the curl command. I wonder why the headers can be different but do the same thing? Also in the Python script, I'm passing this `'json={"method":"update_video", "params":{"video":{"id":"5525001", "itemState":"INACTIVE"}, "token":"jCoXH5OAMY3ysG90YLagEECTP16uOUSg_fEGDAdlhg.."}}'` as a parameter in the POST request

Comment: Like I said, it probably never needed to be multipart because that just seems totally irrelevant. You don't have multiple parts in your post body.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help tonight, much appreciated!